# ASP.NET can't reference class

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I've moved the CS files out the `App_Data` folder because I get errors with duplicate builds, one builds at compile time one at run time so I was told to move them out that folder.

Two files, Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace CrystalTech
{
    public partial class newVersion_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginInitialiser loginData = new LoginInitialiser();
            loginData.loadData();
        }
    }
}
```

And Security.cs

```
namespace CrystalTech
{
    // Handles all our login logic
    public class LoginInitialiser
    {
        public bool isLoggedIn { get; private set; }

        public LoginInitialiser()
        {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }

        // Fetches the users data
        public void loadData()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedIn"] != null)
            {
                this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedIn"];
            }

            // Fetch the data if we are logged in
            if (this.isLoggedIn)
            {

            }
            // Otherwise redirect
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../logins/index.asp?action=dn&r=" + CommonFunctions.GetCurrentPageName());
            }
        }
    }

    // Holds users information
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public string username { get; private set; }
        public Company company { get; private set; }
        public string title { get; private set; }
        public string forenames { get; private set; }
        public string surnames { get; private set; }
        public string email { get; private set; }
    }

    // Holds company information
    public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public string name { get; private set; }
        public string telephone { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Why does Default.aspx.cs throw:

> The type or namespace name 'LoginInitialiser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your classes to live somewhere other than App_Code, add a "Class Library" project to your solution and put that class there. Don't forget to reference that project in your webproject.

Comment: This is the only way if you're wading around in a Web Site project. For full control over namespaces you need to re-organise it as a Web Application project.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240342/confusion-with-root-namespace-in-asp-net-web-project/3547880#3547880

Answer (score 1):

Only code in the App_Code directory is compiled - So unless your files are in there (or a subdirectory), they won't be picked up

And what do you mean by duplicate builds? Depending on project settings, the actual build can be triggered either by the first visit to the site or by the compile itself. It's also possible to do half-and-half. with a little preparation beforehand on (build/publish) and the actual compile on the first site visit

Comment: That's true for web site project, I should mention, not for web app project.

Comment: You're right, and afaik OP has web site project. I just mentioned for others :)

Comment: Sorry yeah this is a web site project.

Comment: @Basiclife - I don't understand your comment, what does the file and tag have to do with the comment abatischev gave? Your answer is relevant to a Web Site project, not a Web Application project. Both website and webapp have .aspx files and fall under asp.net tag...

Comment: @Phil You know, I'm obviously having a slow day - You're quite right. I completely misread what he'd said and thought he was saying web app project vs other projects (Console/Winforms). I'll delete the comment

Comment: Coffee time ;) we all have those days. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code files (except the ones related to aspx files) are put in the `App_Code` folder only to ensure their compilation (This is requirement imposed by ASP.net  and now I know from comments it is only for `web site` projects and not `web application` projects). If they are anywhere else they are not compiled. Check and you will not find `Build Action` for the code files outside `App_Code` folder.