# Visual Studio 2015 recreates .Designer.vb files with wrong namespace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compilation

I had a Web Site project that I copied (converted) to a new Web Application project (all my problems started here).  My root namespace in my project properties was changed, but somehow VisualStudio is generating my designer.vb files using the wrong (old) namespace.

I tried to fix the name in the designer file, but it is regenerated when I rebuild my solution.

Also some of my controls (ascx) also have this problem, the Inherits="wrongNamespace.className" which is problably related.

How do I fix this, so it uses the namespace that is in my project properties?

Comment: The answer in the linked question does not fix the my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a similar post: [Confusion with Root Namespace in Asp.net web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240342/confusion-with-root-namespace-in-asp-net-web-project)

Basically there is no solution except that when you create a project, you can't really change the root namespace without causing this problem.  So I will create a new project with the correct namespace and add my files to this new project.

I wish I could delete some temporary files somewhere, but no luck with that so far.